# java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable on periodical http get, android

Tags: android, sockets

I try to get device setting info using http get method on every 30 seconds, I always succeed in frist two http request/response on my Android device,

```
08-25 19:42:47.789: DEBUG/LitDebug(25907): RestClient: GET, URL = http://www.LockItTight.com/devices/10627.json?device_key=A0000028F3CA5A
08-25 19:42:48.219: DEBUG/LitDebug(25907): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But I will then get the following exception in the following http request/response:

```
08-25 19:43:32.789: DEBUG/LitDebug(25907): RestClient: GET, URL = http://www.LockItTight.com/devices/10627.json?device_key=A0000028F3CA5A
08-25 19:43:32.799: DEBUG/LitDebug(25907): RestClient: GET, java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable
```

I don't have this problem on SDK, here is my code snippet:

`

```
 try {       
        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.LockItTight.com/devices/10627.json?device_key=A0000028F3CA5A");

        // Execute HTTP Get request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Logger.log("RestClient: Get, responseCode = " + responseCode);          

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Logger.log("RestClient: GET, " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.log("RestClient: GET, " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log("RestClient: GET, " + e.toString());
    }
```

`
Could somebody tell me why my code succeed in SDK but fail on device?

Comment: When say succeed in SDK do you mean an AVD (android virtual device)?

Comment: Yes, it means AVD, I only have problem on the physical device, I try to close the http connection by "httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();" after each http get, but this problem still exist.